# Is there any way I can open a link on my site (or navigate to a different page in general) using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking everywhere for SOME sort of information on if I can do this, and if so, HOW?

I was supposed to make a PowerPoint for an eCommerce assignment, and instead asked to make a webpage since I prefer to write HTML than work with PowerPoint. I was talking to the person beside me and eventually he bet me I couldn't get my site to look and work like a PowerPoint, so I took him up on it. So is there any way possible I can go from one page to the next by pressing, let's say the right arrow? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: so you're talking about sliding in the next "page" not actually changing pages

Comment: I was hoping to actually change pages

Comment: Uhm, style an anchor like an arrow, problem solved ?

Comment: `window.location.href="/page2.html";` to change pages

Comment: yeah cant you just use anchor tags? If not you can use window.location on a button click, or if you dont want the appearance of the page "changing" you can make an ajax call to load the next page on click

Answer (score 1):

Use Impress js: http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/

It is a jquery plugin for powerpoint-like slide presentations (and offers much more)

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to make a website look like a PowerPoint application.
With jQuery (which is my favourite JavaScript library) it's easy to identify key strokes.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 39){
    //Right arrow key, now trigger an event or a function. Could be for example: loading new data into a div with ajax or sliding your content so that the next screen is shown.        
}
});
```

See this page to identify Char Codes: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

jQuery also offers the animate method (https://api.jquery.com/animate/) that can be used to make smooth animations, slides, and what not. With knowledge in HTML,CSS and jQuery you can quite easily make an application similar to PowerPoint.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple with standard javascript (I.E. no need to download a library).

Assuming that each page has its own URL you should be able to add an "onkeypress" event onto the body that performs actions based on the particular key pressed using `event.keyCode`.

E.g.

```
<script>
function navigate( event ) {
  if ( event.keyCode == 39 ) {
    // right arrow pressed
    window.location.href = "the url of your next page";
  }

  if ( event.keyCode == 37 ) {
    // left arrow pressed
    window.location.href = "the url of your previous page";
  }
}

</script>
<body onkeypress="navigate( event )">
...
```

There are more elegant solutions, but this should get you started.

Once you have the principle basically working you can find out what the keyCodes are with a `console.log( event.keyCode );`, or look them up online (there are plenty of reference sites out there)